# Can't Install Win2k8 On KVM - Classic 0x80070013 error

Tags: windows-server-2008, kvm-virtualization, drivers

I am trying to install Win2k8 Std as a KVM guest on Debian Squeeze.

As you can see from these screen shots;

1. No drives are detected (I have blanked out a 20GB image for testing) - [screenshot1](http://i47.tinypic.com/xm8hmq.png)
2. I  am using [this](http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win/latest/images/bin/) driver CD:  - [screenshot2](http://i48.tinypic.com/2rq0htz.png)
3. I have signed the Win7 driver (I assume this was the most appropriate one?) - [screenshot3](http://i50.tinypic.com/10hocp5.png)
4. I can now see an unpartitioned drive - [screenshot4](http://i45.tinypic.com/11kjh5c.png)
5. But I can't create a new partition on here, getting the error code 0x80070013 - [screenshot5](http://i49.tinypic.com/elbgbo.png)

I have had this error code before but only on a physical server. If I remember correctly it was complaining because the disks were partitioned as GPT (because it was a server that was being re-purposed) so repartitioning with an MS-DOS table fixed that. This is a blank disk image though. What is wrong here, and how can I correct this?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have booted the VM with a Gparted-Live disk and formatted this volume with an MS-DOS partitioning scheme, and a single 20GB NTFS file system. Now when I boot the Win2k8 CD, load my drivers, I get a different error. As you can see at the bottom of [screenshot6](http://i46.tinypic.com/67sdcn.png)

"*Windows cannot be installed on this hard drive space. Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS*".

Clicking format produces the error (0x80004005) on the screen, so I think this is still a driver issue  because Windows can see the drive but not interact with it properly. Is that insane thinking?

Comment: What happens if you remove any partitions from the windows installer, and lets it create them itself?

Comment: Sadly this isn't working, I have deleted the NTFS partition with a Gparted live CD and now I get the same error as in screenshot5 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a LOT of Googling, I learned that 0x80070013 [means](https://superuser.com/q/154622/144961): `The media is write-protected.` Make sure you didn't set the hard drive as read-only when you configured the virtual machine.

Comment: I don't think that is my problem as I have been able to reformat the drive with a Gparted Live CD?

Comment: I think you should try @cstamas's [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/423993/126632). That's exactly how I always install Windows in a KVM virtual machine and it 100% works.

Comment: Whilst this is not entirely the correct answer, You lead me in the right direction. After reading this I was convinced it was a problem with the disk, but not that it was write protected. I think I needed to erase the image and make a new one, instead I deleted the VM definition, image, and everything, and started fresh. Now it's working. I think the disk I created originally (through an external tool/script) didn't have the correct geometry (the new ones has a different heads and sectors count). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

That (VERY UNHELPFUL) error means you forgot to put the Windows install disk back in.

Comment: As its a virtual machine, the ISO is always mounted.

Comment: Didn't you replace the install ISO with the driver ISO at some point?

Comment: No, I have configured it with 2 CD drives, one with each ISO in.

Comment: Ah, terribly sorry then. I had this exact problem literally just this past week. Not having the install disk mounted was the cause in my case.

Comment: Searching the Internet that error code seems quite generic and people seems to be having it for multiple reasons, so thanks for having a go! :)

Comment: I wanted to be sure it didn't have anything to do with the install ISO. So I just tried replicating your issue by trying the installation on KVM with two IDE cd drives, but mine is installing fine after loading the drivers.

Comment: What driver are you using for use with KVM?

Comment: Same ISO as you, the KVM drivers from the Fedora project.

Comment: I see, and how have you set KVM to emulate the drive, as IDE or SCSI?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4722/discussion-between-kenny-rasschaert-and-javano)

Answer (score 2):

The way I did it is the following:

1. I overwritten the disk image (when the VM was down) by hand just to be sure.

   ```
   qemu-img create -f raw disk0 40G
   ```
2. I chose ide as a disk type.
3. Did the install as normal, ide drivers are integrated in the installer.
4. After completing the install I mounted the CD with virtio drivers and added a new disk with a virtio type.

   ```
   # socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/ganeti/kvm-hypervisor/ctrl/somehost.monitor
   (qemu) pci_add auto storage file=somedisk,if=virtio
   ```
5. The new hardware found dialog came up and I installed the driver successfully.
6. Starting the VM again with the main disk (the 2nd disk in not needed anymore) in virtio mode should work.

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't even have considered anything like this because I'd think the Windows HAL wouldn't like it and would throw a BSOD. Glad to know about this approach.

Comment: This is a good idea I have seen a few people use, +1 for posting it here for others to see I know it does work :)

Comment: It depends on the installer if it accepts the virtio drivers or not at install time. I have one which does and another one which does not. That's why I do it this way.